# Finding and printing nodes in a cycle or in a dead end based on DFS in an undirected graph

Tags: python, depth-first-search, cycle, undirected-graph

I have an exercise for university where I have to write an extended DFS algorithm.
Based on the DFS, I have to specify a procedure that traverses an undirected, continuous graph, classifying each node according to whether it is part of a cycle or a dead end and print the nodes which are in the cycle or in the dead end.
This procedure must be applied to the graphs shown with start node S.
[The drawn graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YNb.png)

I have the following adjacency list:

```
'S' : ['A']
'A' : ['B','F']
'B' : ['C','H']
'C' : ['D','B']
'D' : ['C','E','G']
'E' : ['D','F']
'F' : ['A','E']
'G' : ['D']
'H' : ['B','I']
'I' : ['H']
```

I have mapped each node to the following numbers:

```
0: S
1: A
2: B
3: C
4: D
5: E
6: F
7: G
8: H
9: I
```

Here is the code I have written so far for detecting a cycle in a graph (**edited**):

```py
# Python Program to detect cycle in an undirected graph 
from collections import defaultdict

visitedList = list()
nodes = set()
s = ''


# This class represents a undirected graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, vertexCount):
        self.V = vertexCount  # No. of vertices
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)  # default dictionary to store graph

    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self, v, w):
        self.graph[v].append(w)  # Add w to v_s list
        self.graph[w].append(v)  # Add v to w_s list
        nodes.add(v)
        nodes.add(w)
        # print(self.graph)

    # A recursive function that uses visited[] and parent to detect
    # cycle in subgraph reachable from vertex v.
    def isCyclicUtil(self, v, visited, parent, cycle=list()):
        global s
        visited[v] = True
        visitedList.append(v)
        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        for i in self.graph[v]:
            # If the node is not visited then recurse on it
            if not visited[i]:
                cycle.append(i)
                if self.isCyclicUtil(i, visited, v, cycle):
                    return
            # If an adjacent vertex is visited and not parent of current vertex,
            # then there is a cycle
            elif parent != i:
                s = 'Nodes in a cycle: '
                s += ' '.join(str(v) for v in cycle)
                s += '\nNodes in a dead end: '
                s += ' '.join(str(v) for v in Diff(nodes, cycle))
                #return
                return True
        return cycle

    # Returns true if the graph contains a cycle, else false.
    def isCyclic(self):
        # Mark all the vertices as not visited
        visited = [False] * (self.V)
        cycle = list()
        # Call the recursive helper function to detect cycle in different 
        # DFS trees
        for i in range(self.V):
            if not visited[i]:  # Don't recur for u if it is already visited
                if self.isCyclicUtil(i, visited, -1, cycle):
                    return True
        return False


def Diff(li1, li2):
    return list(list(set(li1) - set(li2)) + list(set(li2) - set(li1)))


# Driver code
# Create a graph with given adjacency list
S = 0
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
E = 5
F = 6
G = 7
H = 8
I = 9

g = Graph(10)

g.addEdge(S, A)
g.addEdge(A, B)
g.addEdge(B, C)
g.addEdge(B, H)
g.addEdge(C, D)
g.addEdge(D, E)
g.addEdge(D, G)
g.addEdge(E, F)
g.addEdge(F, A)
g.addEdge(H, I)


if g.isCyclic():
    print("Graph contains cycle")
    print(s)
else:
    print("Graph does not contain cycle")

'''
g = Graph(6)

g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(1, 3)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 4)
g.addEdge(4, 5)

if g.isCyclic():
    print("Graph contains cycle")
    print(s)
else:
    print("Graph does not contain cycle")
'''
```

What is still missing here is to print the nodes that are in the cycle or in the dead end.

Comment: don't compare booleans to a boolean constant, use the boolean or **not** boolean. No need of `()` around an `if` expression (it is not C++), if the parameter of a method is the number of vertices don't call it `vertices` but something like `vertexCount`, `self.V` is not a very descriptive name, in 6 months you will be confused

Comment: pass the visited notes to the util func and return a modified list if found a cycle and print this list

Comment: @rioV8 I have added the cycle which which I return when a cycle is found. The thing is that when I change the arrangement of addEdge then it doesn't work correctly but also for the another graph at the bottom of the code (see my edited code).

Comment: `return cycle`: a non-empty list is "True", get rid of the global variables, use the node names and not a mapping to numbers, never use a `list()` as default argument, use a debugger to see what else is wrong in the recursive logic